# Filling in missing values in one dataframe from another with no primary key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have a table `A` with `ID` as the primary key on couples:

| ID | Age Life 1 | Name Life 1 | Age Life 2 | Name Life 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  | 15 | Nancy |
| 2 | 20 |  |  | John |

I have another data table `G`, which is a huge mess and has no primary key, but the Life indicator tells us which life it contains:

| Row | ID | Age | Name | Life | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | Yuki | 1 | 2018-05-30 |
| 2 | 1 | 10 | Jim | 1 | 2018-10-30 |
| 3 | 2 | 20 | Catherine | 1 | 2018-05-06 |
| 4 | 1 | 10 | Nancy | 2 | 2018-12-31 |
| 5 | 2 | 30 | John | 2 | 2018-10-02 |
| 6 | 1 | 10 | Caleb | 1 | 2015-12-31 |
| 7 | 2 | 20 | Kevin | 1 | 2017-05-06 |
| 8 | 1 | 10 | Bob | 2 | 2020-12-31 |
| 9 | 2 | 15 | Alice | 2 | 2015-10-02 |

I want to update the contents (Name/Age) of table `A` with table `G` such that

For any ID `i` in `A`:

For all rows with ID equal to `i` in `G`

If field `Name` is empty in `A`, and `Date` is between 2018-01-01 and 2018-12-31, and it is of the latest date, I want to take the value from `G` corresponding to the same ID `i`

If field `Age` is empty in `A`, and `Date` is between 2018-01-01 and 2018-12-31, and it is of the latest date, I want to take the value from `G` corresponding to the same ID `i` :

Note that for ID 1, Name Life 1 is Jim, not Yuki, because Jim is the latest one (2018-10-30), whereas Yuki occurred on 2018-05-30

The ending result will look like:

| ID | Age Life 1 | Name Life 1 | Age Life 2 | Name Life 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | Jim | 15 | Nancy |
| 2 | 20 | Catherine | 30 | John |

I can write for loops, but that'd be linear search on ID, which will be very inefficient given the database has a large number of rows and columns. I considered joining the data, but the fact that table `G` has no primary key and IDs are duplicated makes this impossible (I think).

Update:

My dataframe looks like this:

| ID | Date | Life |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 31300000 | 2018-12-31 | 1 |
| 31500000 | 2018-12-31 | 1 |

but I am still getting this error when I call `pivot`.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-223-1d81b8743b42> in <module>
----> 1 rf2 = rf_filtered_test.drop('Date', axis=1).pivot(columns=['Life'], index='ID')

/opt/cloudera/extras/anaconda3-2018/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in pivot(self, index, columns, values)
   5192         """
   5193         from pandas.core.reshape.reshape import pivot
-> 5194         return pivot(self, index=index, columns=columns, values=values)
   5195 
   5196     _shared_docs['pivot_table'] = """

/opt/cloudera/extras/anaconda3-2018/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/reshape.py in pivot(self, index, columns, values)
    398         cols = [columns] if index is None else [index, columns]
    399         append = index is None
--> 400         indexed = self.set_index(cols, append=append)
    401     else:
    402         if index is None:

/opt/cloudera/extras/anaconda3-2018/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in set_index(self, keys, drop, append, inplace, verify_integrity)
   3913             arrays.append(level)
   3914 
-> 3915         index = _ensure_index_from_sequences(arrays, names)
   3916 
   3917         if verify_integrity and not index.is_unique:

/opt/cloudera/extras/anaconda3-2018/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in _ensure_index_from_sequences(sequences, names)
   4909         return Index(sequences[0], name=names)
   4910     else:
-> 4911         return MultiIndex.from_arrays(sequences, names=names)
   4912 
   4913 
lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py in from_arrays(cls, arrays, sortorder, names)
   1268         for i in range(1, len(arrays)):
   1269             if len(arrays[i]) != len(arrays[i - 1]):
-> 1270                 raise ValueError('all arrays must be same length')
   1271 
   1272         from pandas.core.arrays.categorical import _factorize_from_iterables

ValueError: all arrays must be same length
```

Comment: The 30 in your end result doesn't make sense?

Comment: @BeRT2me Good catch. I've corrected it.

Comment: Is there actually a column named `Row` in that df? I also dropped that one in testing~

Comment: @BeRT2me No, that is my addition so rows can be referred by number.

Answer (score 1):

Given your second table:

```
   ID  Age       Name  Life
0   1   10        Jim     1
1   2   20  Catherine     1
2   1   10      Nancy     2
3   2   15       John     2
```

We can:

```
# Pivot it:
df2 = df.pivot(columns=['Life'], index='ID')
# Rename Columns:
df2.columns = [f'{i} Life {j}' if j != '' else f'{i}' for i,j in df2.columns]
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
# Re-order Columns:
df2 = df2[['ID', 'Age Life 1', 'Name Life 1', 'Age Life 2', 'Name Life 2']]
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
   ID  Age Life 1 Name Life 1  Age Life 2 Name Life 2
0   1          10         Jim          10       Nancy
1   2          20   Catherine          15        John
```

Now since the first df has different values than this pivoted one, we can keep those and fill the rest:

```
out = df3.combine_first(df2)
print(out)

...

   ID  Age Life 1 Name Life 1  Age Life 2 Name Life 2
0   1        10.0         Jim        15.0       Nancy
1   2        20.0   Catherine        15.0        John
```

---

Update:

```
# Extract only most recent values that fall in the timeframe:
df_filtered = (df[df.Date.between('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31')]
                 .sort_values('Date', ascending=False)
                 .groupby(['ID', 'Life'])
                 .head(1))
# Now the rest is the same:
df2 = df_filtered.drop('Date', axis=1).pivot(columns=['Life'], index='ID')
df2.columns = [f'{i} Life {j}' if j != '' else f'{i}' for i,j in df2.columns]
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
df2 = df2[['ID', 'Age Life 1', 'Name Life 1', 'Age Life 2', 'Name Life 2']]
out = df3.combine_first(df2)
print(out)
```

Output:

```
   ID  Age Life 1 Name Life 1  Age Life 2 Name Life 2
0   1        10.0         Jim        15.0       Nancy
1   2        20.0   Catherine        15.0        John
```

Comment: On df.pivot(), I am getting `ValueError: all arrays must be same length`. I think this is produced when columns have different length; not sure why this is happening as I don't have multi-level index.

Comment: Sorry about that; I have included a dimension of `Date` in the problem, as I suspect that is causing the error. I initially wanted a solution and hoped that I can tweak it to include the `Date` dimension, but it seems that I wouldn't be able to run it without fixing the `Date`.

Comment: I have put my dataframe and error message in the body of the post as an update. Went to watch videos on pivot, but still not fully understanding. Thank you for the help thus far.